# How to maintain state of a request scope bean without using a4j:keepAlive in richfaces 3 and seam 2?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam, jsf-1.2

I have problem pertaining to the maintaining state of the particular @Request scope bean. I have a Seam Entity List request scope component. And after a particular request i want it to maintain its state and not to be refreshed, `a4j:keepAlive` do the solution but unfortunately using `a4j:keepAlive` destroy some other functionality inside a view so instead changing the whole page i just ignore `a4j:keepAlive`.

My question is, how can i maintain this particular scenario without using `a4j:keepAlive` and without making my component into `@SessionScope` or `@ConversationScope`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JSF 2 for your website development, it would be better to use RichFaces 4. The [RichFaces 3.3](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/TechnicalRequirements.html#SupportedJavaServerFacesImplementations) is built to support JSF 1.2 mainly and then was extended to support JSF 2, still it doesn't take advantages of the benefits from JSF 2. [RichFaces 4.x](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces-Technical_Requirements), in the other hand, is built thinking in JSF 2. It would be wise to move from RF 3.3 to RF 4, but if you still want to stick to RF 3.3, you should change the scope of your bean to ViewScope and stop using the `a4j:keepAlive`.

More info:

- [Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes)

EDIT:

For your given problem, you should save the data in session and recover it when your Request Managed Bean is created, doing that your data will be preserved through your view, but you have to do the job manually (very hard to maintain, also).

If your managed bean has binding attributes with the jsp/facelet you're using, then don't use the `a4j:keepAlive` tag component, instead add the `@KeepAlive(ajaxOnly=false)` annotation to your request managed bean to save the entire state of your bean (even the binding components).

Comment: @EllieFabrero I've updated my answer. It would be better if you expose the code of what you're doing and the pitfall to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer man, i appreciate it. i think i will both try what you are suggesting. I'm thinking to store the data in a session. BTW can i change a certain Scope of a bean or it is fixed? In my scenario i have a table bounded to my entity list with the capability of sorting the table, but after for example send a request and reRender the table, the table goes back to its old sorting so i want to maintain it after a request.

Comment: @EllieFabrero when the table is sorted, the list in your backing bean is also sorted? Maybe when you send the request your list is loaded again (with the old unsorted values), you should test saving your list, do the processing and then recover your list to update your table.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll further investigate the process..I will let you know if i solved it already.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `@ViewScope` : http://balusc.blogspot.fr/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html